# Проблема с перемещением мышкой подгружаемых через THREE.OBJMTLLoader() объектов

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Добрый день!
Пробовал средствами THREE.js создать шахматную доску. При этом фигуры подгружаются в виде объектов. Используются стандартные скрипты из примеров и документации, которые 100% работают.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load(name+'.obj',name+'.mtl', function ( object ) {
objects.push(object);
scene.add(object);
};
```

Скрипт для перехвата перемещений объекта мышкой приводить не буду. Он стандартный и работает (проверено). Проблема в следующем:

1. Подгруженные фигуры (obj-объекты) НИКАК НЕ РАСПОЗНАЮТСЯ скриптами, как объекты сцены, поэтому мышкой перемещать их не удается.
2. Если добавить в сцену любую фигуру командой THREE.Mesh(...), то она без проблем перетаскивается мышкой.
3. Дошел до того, что сверял объекты, загруженные в массиве objects с теми, что есть на сцене (шахматные фигуры). Все отлично, но на фигуры скрипты не реагируют, хотя должны.
4. Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что подгружаемые фигуры не созданы через THREE.Mesh(), поэтому находятся в системе не полноценно. Скорее всего я не прав.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема или ссылочку на работающий пример, где подгружаемые объекты перетаскиваются мышкой.

Comment: После глубокой трассировки структуры объектов я догадался в чем может быть причина. Объект, импортированный в сцену через loader является группой, у которой в чилдренах все куча объектов-треугольников из которых строится фигура. Поэтому стандартные процедуры перехвата движения на объект-группу не реагируют. Нужно либо добавлять в objects ВСЕ треугольнички КАЖДОЙ фигуры либо искать иной алгоритм

Comment: Столкнулся с похожей ситуацией. Из собственных наблюдений заметил, что при загрузке объектов THREE.OBJMTLLoader() добавляет в коллекцию children несколько пустых объектов. У них есть vertices, как и у основного объекта, но отсутствуют faces - коллекция пустая. Поэтому при добавлении в сцену я извлекаю нужный child и добавляю его и в сцену и в массив для коллизии. А массив коллизий оперирует только с классом THREE.Mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Если запихнуть чаилдов по отдельности в массив objects, например, так

```
for (var i=0;i<object.children.length; i++){
    objects.push(object.children[i]);
}
```

то и перемещать по сцене будешь их по отдельности. А как перемещать всю фигуру загруженную через obj мышью целиком? Я ответа пока что не нашел...

Answer (score -3):

попробуй перетаскивать всех потомков , а не сам объект и не через forEach а через nodelist

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?